# How to make an inApp "Chat"

Tags: ios

I'm making an app, the user must have the option to send messages to other users.

Based on this i have the doubt how it works, initially i thought that works with push notifications, but researching about this, it seems that is no the way to do this (or i dont understand a freaking thing).

After that i think "Ok, when the 'chat' controller is open it calls a method every X seconds and look for new messages", but that no make much sense if i see how whatsapp works (I know that is an exaggerated comparison) and i think this will cause a crash or memory problems.

So, i dont know how the app "knows" that there is a new message.

Can anyone please tell me where to start looking?

I'm really lost about this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Ok ok, based on answer, i know a screw it asking this, sorry to all, specially to  moonwave99

Comment: Too much of an open-ended question.  What is wrong with any of the tutorials listed on the link that moonwave posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 0 experience on chat programming but I'll still try to answer your question.

You will need a server to manage the messaging between clients.

Then you could follow two routes:

- Having the client fetch the server for new messages every X seconds (the easiest option if you ask me)
- Having a socket connection between client and server and have the client listen on that socket for incoming messages forwarded by the server (the best option if you ask me)

Developing the first option is not hard at all but the second one will require quite a little bit of studying effort especially if you are new to networking and stuff like that.

**Edit:** To develop the first option you could use a library `AFNetworking` to send an http request to the server and have the server return the incoming messages maybe in the form of JSON or XML data.

Take a look at this for a very good get-started tutorial. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/

Answer (score 2):

Doing this well is an enormous project. Adium (a popular Mac chat app) is about 200,000 lines of code *not counting* the libraries it uses to interact with IM servers.

Depending on how simple you're willing to get, you can do much less than that, but it'll still be a bunch of work. I would suggest starting by looking for XMPP libraries; it's a standardized flexible protocol for this.

Comment: Thanks i will look for that

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using an external system to manage this, the data behind and the push notifications, take a look at Parse.com. I've used it and it will give you a back end and iOS classes to manage this for you.

Comment: Yeah i know Parse make it simple, but i cant use it :/

Comment: ah sorry to hear that :(